# getting parent key not found error in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
insert into employees(employee_id,e_name,department_id)
values (5, 'faizi', 6);
```

---

```
insert into department(loc_id, d_name, department_id)
values (11, 'bba',6);
```

I am getting the following error.  The departmentId is the primary key in the employees table and a foreign key in the department table.  Why am I getting this error?

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYS.SYS_C003995) violated - parent key not found

Comment: Looks the primary key of the `employees` table is `employee_id`. Do you get the error when you try to insert into the `employees` table, or `department` table, or both? Show the actual structure of all the tables.

Comment: department_id is the primary key in employees table. and foreign key in departments table. i inserted values in employees table but when i insert in departments table then i get this error

Comment: Show the actual structure of the tables. In the `employees` table `employee_id` must be the primary key. it doesn't make sense that the `department` table's primary id is not `department_id`. What is the primary key of the `department` table? `loc_id`?

Comment: i just want to know why its not working. i dont want to know that which column should be the primary key. so please focus on what i want to know.

Comment: Show the actual structure of the tables. I'm not telling you what the primary keys should be, what I'm saying is: they probably are not what you think they are. The information you've provided is not enough to debug the issue. Showing the actual structure of the tables might help.

Answer (score 2):

Your insertion order is wrong. You need to insert the department first then the employee that works in that department

Answer (score 2):

For an insert statement, this ORA-02291 error is common when you are trying to insert a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.  In that case, you need to add the parent row to the table and then re-insert your child table row.

Comment: i m inserting the matching value. you can see i am inserting 6 in department_id in both tables. but when i insert in child table. it gives error